# Magento API login method returns null

Tags: web-services, api, magento, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to call some methods from the Magento API V.1, but when I call the `startSession` method to get a sessionId, I receive *null* as a result. I'm using Magento 1.5.1.0. Here is my code (I have to save the WSDL file locally before creating the SOAP client due to a bug in PHP 5.3 related to large WSDL files.):

```
        // Create a SOAP client
    $data = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl");
    file_put_contents("wsdl.xml", $data);
    $proxy = new SoapClient("wsdl.xml");

    // Log-in to the magento API
    $sessionId = $proxy -> login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
```

This is the full POST request sent to Magento:

```
POST /magento/index.php/api/soap/index/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8070
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"
Content-Length: 383

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <ns1:startSession/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

And this is the (empty) POST response received from Magento:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2011 14:57:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8k PHP/5.3.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.0
Location: http://127.0.0.1/magento/
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Has anyone encountered this before? I find it strange that I don't get a SOAP message at all in the returned data.

Thanx :)

**UPDATE:** At this point I still don't know the cause of this problem, and I've simply switched to a fresh install of Magento on a different machine. It seems to be working fine there.

Comment: Dumb question but, is the PHP SOAP extension installed and enabled in your environment?

Comment: Actually, `/api/soap/?wsdl` is soap v1 wsdl,  you need `api/v2_soap?wsdl=1` url to get soap v2 wsdl.

Comment: @B00MER Yes, the PHP SOAP extension is installed and enabled, I double-checked it right now.

Comment: @Zyava Yes, you are right. I was actually using the SOAP V1 WSDL. However, I tried starting a session using the SOAP V2 WSDL and observed exactly the same behavior (empty HTTP POST response).

Comment: try `var_dump($proxy->__getLastRequest())` and `var_dump($proxy->__getLastResponse())` after `$proxy -> login('apiUser', 'apiKey')` to see what is sent to magento and what it returns.

Comment: @Zyava Strangely, both var-dumps return null. However, using a TCP monitoring tool I can see the SOAP request being sent and an empty reply being received.

Comment: Don't know then. Something is wrong with your php and/or soap extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you call file_get_contents it

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl");
file_put_contents("wsdl.xml", $data);
$proxy = new SoapClient("wsdl.xml");
```

change with this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

// If you don't need the session anymore
$client->endSession($session);
```

Comment: i want to get products info, my code : https://justpaste.it/4yyqf and my output : https://snag.gy/y7iZav.jpg  can you pls help me to solve the error? @Josua Marcel Chrisano

Comment: please wait @Gem , i will check it now

Comment: Okay, i am waiting @Josua Marcel Chrisano

Comment: may i know the real url? @gem

Comment: I have no right to share those details, i hope you understand my every details tracking. Can i get help for basic trobleshooting @Josua Marcel Chrisano

Comment: Sorry @Gem i cannot do anything without the details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183628/discussion-between-josua-marcel-chrisano-and-gem).